# Is a DiskWarrior warning about spare blocks applicable to SSDs?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, hardware, ssd, sata

I got the following warning from DiskWarrior on my Mac Pro in which I installed a SATA SSD:

[image: DiskWarrior warning]

I know some sort of reassignments are normal on an SSD as it comes from the factory. However, I don't know if this message is normal. I've had this drive for about a year with light use. The Documents, iPhoto and iTunes libraries are on a different disk.

- Hardware: MacPro4,1 flashed to a MacPro5,1
- OS: macOS 10.13.6
- Disk SW: DiskWarrior 5.1
- Disk: Crucial MX300 525GB 3D NAND SATA 2.5 Inch Internal SSD - CT525MX300SSD1
- Disk Installed: 2/7/2017

[Other users on forums have reported similar errors](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=1288067) from DiskWarrior with regards to SSDs even after a brand-new SSD is installed. How can I tell if this alert is dire or a sign of imminent boot drive failure?

smartctl reports:

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       24
  5 Reallocate_NAND_Blk_Cnt 0x0032   099   099   010    Old_age   Always       -       18
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       331
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       26
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Ave_Block-Erase_Count   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       10
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
183 SATA_Interfac_Downshift 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 Error_Correction_Count  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   074   057   000    Old_age   Always       -       26 (Min/Max 19/43)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       18
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
202 Percent_Lifetime_Used   0x0030   100   100   001    Old_age   Offline      -       0
206 Write_Error_Rate        0x000e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
246 Total_Host_Sector_Write 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4371671528
247 Host_Program_Page_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       138423264
248 Bckgnd_Program_Page_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       69337024
180 Unused_Reserve_NAND_Blk 0x0033   000   000   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       1929
210 Success_RAIN_Recov_Cnt  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       74

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged
```

The two values that match the DiskWarrior error are `Reallocated_Event_Count` and `Reallocate_NAND_Blk_Cnt`. If I'm interpreting `Reallocate_NAND_Blk_Cnt` correctly, the raw value is 18, this maps to 99% remaining. Once there's 10% remaining, an error will be thrown.

Whereas, for my spinning disk, `Reallocated_Event_Count` is:

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

Perhaps DiskWarrior believes that `Reallocated_Event_Count` counts up to a raw value threshold of 10 and it's beyond that now?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  If you don’t get some good answers in a few hours or days, consider using th edit button to add the version of macOS and disk warrior you run. My guess is this is false positive or a bad reading but I’d hate to be wrong without more specifics or put up a proper answer.

Comment: Have you checked with the developer of DiskWarrior? Have a look at [To Contact Technical Support:](https://www.alsoft.com/Support/index.html) and or [Online Technical Support Form](https://www.alsoft.com/Support/techsupportform.html) at Alsoft's web site.

Comment: @user3439894 - I haven't checked with the developer yet. Other users have checked with the developer in similar instances and the developer just said the HD was bad while the drive manufacturer said the drive was good. I suspect DiskWarrior is misinterpreting the SMART status.

Comment: Personally, before posting a question such as this, I would have done at least the following : 1. Check with the drive manufacture to see what diagnostic software is available from them to test the drive and test it, or software other then the software in question. 2. Contact the developer of the software in question. That said, from a post at Crucial's Forum I found [GSmartControl](https://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.io/home/index.php/Downloads). - [Re: Any way to check the health of an ssd?](https://forums.crucial.com/t5/SSD-Archive-Read-Only/Any-way-to-check-the-health-of-an-ssd/td-p/138291).

Comment: It's an older post, but maybe using GSmartControl will provide additional info to help determine whether or not DiskWarrior is misreading the SMART status.